# Javascript how to get non duplicates data from array?

Tags: javascript

```
let getNonDuplicates = [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5]; // Here's my example array
```

the result I needed is to get 1 & 5 since those are the data that don't have duplicates

```
let resultMustBe = [1,5];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `filter` method, to filter the array, based on the condition that index of an element from beginning is equal to index of the same element from the last. It means that the element is unique in the array.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5];

let res = arr.filter(e=>arr.indexOf(e)===arr.lastIndexOf(e));

console.log(res);
```